# How to expand the space of the partition /dev/sdf4 until the end of the sdcard ? Neither resize2fs nor gparted work correctly

Tags: ubuntu, partition, gparted, gpt, resize2fs

I would like to resize the /dev/sdf4 partition located on the sd card mounted on my Ubuntu 22.04 distro. I tried to accomplish this task using two approaches :

1. using the command resizefs,but it failed :

**mario@Z390-AORUS-PRO-DEST:/media/ziomario/Elements/Backup/ChromeBook# resize2fs /dev/sdf4 resize2fs 1.46.5 (30-Dec-2021). The filesystem is already 1174779 (4k) blocks long. Nothing to do!**

2. I've tried with gparted,but it also failed. This is what I did :

[image: 1]
**: this is the partition that I want to extend...**

[image: 2]
**: from 4589 to 180577...**

[image: 3]
**: ...as you can see it asks if I want to continue with the current settings. If I say "yes",it will not resize the partition. If I say "no",it will resize the partition and it will fix the error that you see,but when I insert the sd card inside the netbook,ubuntu installed on the sd card will not boot.**

This is what happens when I try to resize the partition :

https://ibb.co/5My7q7s

I can't neither resize sdf4 nor I can create a new ext4 partition on the unallocated space :(

https://ibb.co/FqskSSh

https://ibb.co/3k8dnYZ

This is the log messages that I see on the Terminal :

```
mario@Z390-AORUS-PRO-DEST:/media/ziomario/Elements/Backup/ChromeBook# gparted /dev/sdf
GParted 1.3.1
configuration --enable-libparted-dmraid --enable-online-resize
libparted 3.4
Not all of the space available to /dev/sdf appears to be used, you can fix the GPT to use all of the space (an extra 369821696 blocks) or continue with the current setting? 
Not all of the space available to /dev/sdf appears to be used, you can fix the GPT to use all of the space (an extra 369821696 blocks) or continue with the current setting? 

** (gpartedbin:44337): WARNING **: 20:16:57.049: invalid substitution "%s" in fmt string "percorso: %1 (%s)"
Not all of the space available to /dev/sdf appears to be used, you can fix the GPT to use all of the space (an extra 369821696 blocks) or continue with the current setting? 
Unable to satisfy all constraints on the partition.
Not all of the space available to /dev/sdf appears to be used, you can fix the GPT to use all of the space (an extra 369821696 blocks) or continue with the current setting? 
Not all of the space available to /dev/sdf appears to be used, you can fix the GPT to use all of the space (an extra 369821696 blocks) or continue with the current setting? 
Not all of the space available to /dev/sdf appears to be used, you can fix the GPT to use all of the space (an extra 369821696 blocks) or continue with the current setting?
```

Comment: A gpt partitioned drive as a backup gpt partition table at end of drive. Is this a copy from a smaller drive, so backup gpt is in middle of drive? `sudo gdisk /dev/sdf'  launch gdisk, then type x, then type e, then type w to save your changes http://www.rodsbooks.com/gdisk/repairing.html & http://askubuntu.com/questions/386752/fixing-corrupt-backup-gpt-table/386802#386802

Comment: ok I did it. now ? what should I do ? I tried to expand the root partition sdf4 with gparted but it failed again.

Comment: this is the error I get when I try to resize the root fs with gnome-disks : https://ibb.co/7zbXJqk

Comment: That error is most common with Windows hibernated files. But as message says can be anything that is corrupted. Post gdisk output in question above.

Comment: which command should I issue ?

Comment: `sudo gdisk /dev/sdf` to see if you still have issues.

Comment: https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/qnNSwJbNZ2/

Comment: You do not show that you did the w to write the changes? No need to show the command options, just the commands you run & what it returns. Then just a few lines you can post in question above as code.

Comment: https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/Zs44XmN2n7/

Comment: Why did you change GUID/partUUID? I thought we were moving backup partition table to end of drive. You have to change UEFI & anyplace else that uses the old GUID. Not sure if 7 blocks is critical or not?

Comment: I have followed this tutorial : https://www.frakkingsweet.com/expand-ext4-disk-in-debian-10/ ; why you say that I have changed them ? It does not seem to me. Sure,the 7 blocks are critical. If I fix that error,ubuntu installed on the sd card will not boot anymore.

Comment: What drive is this? Brand name drive from reliable vendor? We have seen where someone purchases a "cheap" external SSD or flash drive that says it is large but really is small.

Comment: it is an high quality sd card.